# AR on Non-Linear Time Serires

Tags: regression, forecasting, autoregressive

Should autoregressive model be able to fit and forecast non-linear time series, for example, a sine curve (by non-linear I mean the data generating process)? I used `ar()` function in R to automatically select order and perform an AR model on a sine curve of length 1000; then predict another 1000 points:

```
t <- seq(0, 50, 0.05)
train <- ts(sin(t))
model <- ar(train)
pred <- predict(model, n.ahead = 1000)[[1]]
plot(ts(c(train, pred)))
```

The result is as follows:

```
Coefficients:
      1        2        3        4        5        6        7  
 1.2551  -0.0654  -0.0482  -0.0351  -0.0251  -0.0172  -0.0108  
      8        9  
-0.0054  -0.0563  

Order selected 9  sigma^2 estimated as  7.645e-05
```

The prediction (first 1000 real data, last 1000 predictions) looks like:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Why does AR seem to fit the frequency well?
2. Why does the amplitude shrink over time in the prediction?